# window location href inside jquery replaceWith tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, replacewith

thanks for the amazing community, i'm strugling with this code i'm tring to load href link with window.location.href + string '/1/' into my jquery replaceWith tag but no luck could you help me please
this is my code:

```js
var myhref=window.location.href+'/1/':
$j('.the-tag p').replaceWith('<a href="'.myhref.'">My Link</a>');
```

thank you for your help again

Comment: FYI, you have a syntax error at the end of your first line. You probably meant to use `;` instead of `:`. Also, the string concatenation operator is `+`, not `.`

Comment: @Phil the issue is my href doesn't print the variable myhref and return error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like below ? You need to include jquery library files, and then below will work. In the code I have fixed : at the end of line 1 to ;

```js
var myhref = window.location.href + '/1/';
$('.the-tag p').replaceWith('<a href="' + myhref + '">My Link</a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the-tag">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you that what i was looking for, really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

Some problems with your current script...

1. Your first line is terminated with `:` which causes a syntax error. You probably meant `;`
2. To concatenate strings in JS, you use the `+` operator
3. Your script appends `/1/` to the end of the complete URL. If the URL contains query parameters or fragments, this will cause problems. You should manipulate the path property only

```js
// Show an example with a fragment location
location.hash = "#anchor"

// Clone the current URL
const myhref = new URL(location)

// Handles cases where the current path
// does or does not end in a "/"
myhref.pathname = myhref.pathname.replace(/\/?$/, "/1/")

$('.the-tag p').replaceWith($("<a>", {
  href: myhref,
  text: "My Link"
}))
```

```css
/* This is just so you can see the href */
a::after {
  content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  color: grey;
  font-size: .8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="the-tag" id="anchor">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead

```
var myhref = window.location.href+'/1/';
$.('.the-tag p').replaceWith('<a href="'+ myhref +'">My Link</a>');
```

And also you should ensure that you have the Jquery library included added in your code as well.